# Determine if $b$ is in the span of $x$ and $y$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $$x= \begin{bmatrix}
        2 \\
        0 \\
        1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}, y = \begin{bmatrix}
        5 \\
        1 \\
        1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$$

Determine if $$c= \begin{bmatrix}
        0 \\
       -2 \\
        3  \\
        \end{bmatrix}$$ is in the span of $x$ and $y$.

So I went about this by creating an augmented matrix as follows:
\begin{bmatrix}
        2 & 5 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & -2 \\
        1 & 1 & 3 \\
        \end{bmatrix}

then through elementary row operations I was left with 
\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 1 & 3 \\
        0 & 1 & -2 \\
        0 & 3 & -6 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
then through back substitution I created the equations $p+w=3$, $w=-2$, and $3w=-6$. I then solved for $p$ and go it equal to $5$. Since $p=5$ and $w=-2$ satisfies both equations does that mean $b$ is in the span of $x$ and $y$. Did I solve this correctly?

Comment: You might want to look at http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference again and scroll all the way down to matrices.

Comment: Is $x = (2,0,1)$ or $(1,2,0)$? You seem to have both in your question.

Comment: my bad I made a mistake! I edited the question!

Answer (score 3):

You can compute the determinant, see that
$$\begin{vmatrix}1&5&0\\2&1&-2\\0&1&3\end{vmatrix}=5-2\cdot 15=-25\neq 0,$$
and so $(x,y,c)$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3,$ and thus $c\not\in\mathrm{span}(x,y).$

The error would be that you have written $(2,0,1)$ instead of $(1,2,0),$ as Aurey told you.

---

**Edit** :

You can first note that $x,y$ is a free family, and that

$$\begin{vmatrix}2&5&0\\0&1&-2\\1&1&3\end{vmatrix}=2\cdot5-10=0,$$
so the only remainig possibility is that $c\in\mathrm{span}(x,y).$

Comment: my apologies I made a mistake! I edited the question.

Comment: @Lil : I edited the answer so !

Comment: how do you compute the determinant? what positions are multiplied? I have not learned it yet...

Comment: @Lil : Do you know about Gaussian elimination ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't even have to do backwards substitutions. Just proceed further to put the matrix in row echelon form: you get
$$\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 1 & 3 \\
        0 & 1 & -2 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$$
Thus the augmented matrix has rank $2$, like $\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 5 \\
        2 & 1 \\
        0 & 1\\
        \end{bmatrix}$. This means vector $\begin{bmatrix}
        3 \\ -2 \\ 0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$ belongs to the span ofthe first two column-vectors.

**Note:**

The same method  provides automatically an equation of this span, i.e. the condition for $(x,y,z)$  to be in the span:

\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 5 & x \\
        2 & 1 & y \\
        0 & 1 & z \\
        \end{bmatrix} \to
\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 5 & x \\
        0 & 1 & z \\
        2 & 1 & y \\
        \end{bmatrix} \to
\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 5 & x \\
        0 & 1 & z \\
        0 & -9 & -2x + y \\
        \end{bmatrix}\to
\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 5 & x \\
        0 & 1 & z \\
        0 & 0 & -2x + y + 9z \\
        \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
Thus the equation of the span is the compatibility condition:
$$2x-y-9z=0$$

Answer (score 0):

If $c$ is in the span of $x$ $y$ then $$c=a \begin{bmatrix}
        2 \\
        0 \\
        1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}+b \begin{bmatrix}
        5 \\
        1 \\
        1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$$ you have to solve a linear system to determine $a$ and $b$. If the linear system hasn't solutions then $c$ isn't in the span of $x$ and $y$

Comment: I have not learned the determinant yet. Is my answer correct the way I approached the problem?

Comment: Yes, your approach is correct

Answer (score 0):

If $c  \in span\{x,y\}$, then $c$ can be expressed as a linear combination of $x$ and $y$:

$$c = \alpha x + \beta y$$

Thus you only have to solve the linear equation system

$$\begin{bmatrix}
        0 \\
       -2 \\
        3  \\
        \end{bmatrix} = \alpha \begin{bmatrix}
        2 \\
        0 \\
        1 \\
        \end{bmatrix} + \beta \begin{bmatrix}
        5 \\
        1 \\
        1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$$

Which is

$$ 2\alpha + 5 \beta = 0$$
$$  \beta = -2$$
$$ \alpha +  \beta = 3$$

with solutions $\alpha = 5$ and $\beta = -2$. Thus $c  \in span\{x,y\}$.

Comment: It's equal to my answer